# TAutoObjectFactory.Create - ошибка доступа

Tags: delphi, com, ole

Достался чужой проект, который при запуске под не администратором выдает ошибку "Ошибка при обращении к доступу OLE". Экспериментальным путем пришел к тому, что ошибка возникает на момент инициализации проекта после строк

```
    initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TClassMine, Class_ClassMine,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
```

В Интернете находил решения связанные с добавлением пользователей в группу DCOM, однако это не помогло.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, тугосоображающему в какую сторону копать?

Comment: `TClassMine` из того же проекта? Покажете нам его конструктор?

Answer (score 0):

Помогла вот такая вот заглушка (работает при локальном использовании объектов):

```
unit AutoObjHack;
interface
uses SysUtils,ComObj,ComServ; 

implementation
var
SaveInitProc: Pointer;

procedure MyInitComServer;
begin
  if SaveInitProc <> nil then begin
   try
     TProcedure(SaveInitProc);
   except
    on E: EOleSysError do begin
      //do nothing
    end;
   else
     raise;
   end;
  end; 
end;
initialization

  SaveInitProc := InitProc;
  InitProc := @MyInitComServer;

end.
```

При глобальном пользовании без разового доступа под администратором никак нельзя.